# Javascript hash map with 2 values

Tags: javascript

Is There a way to do an hash map in `javascript` that holds 1 key and 2 values?

For an hash map with key and value in `javascript` i can do something like this:

```
var userList = {
     11234321:"koko",
     22342342:"jojo",
     32342423:"fofo",
     42342342:"momo"                    
    }
```

So for each ID number i have user name.

Now, i want to add another value, like: user age.

There is a way to do that? any other solution to the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially what you're asking for is a multidimensional associative array. The JavaScript implementation of that is nested objects, along these lines:

```
var userList = {
    11234321:{
        "username": "koko",
        "age": 24
    },
    22342342:{
        "username": "jojo",
        "age": 33
    },
    ...
};
```

Note that there is no limit to how deep these nests go.

To access a particular username, for example, you would access `userList[id]['username']` (or `userList[id].username`), just like an associative array in other languages.

Comment: How can i iterate userList? in my example i can do: var it = Iterator(userList)

Comment: `for( id in userList) {... do stuff with userList[k] ...}`

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend having the value as another hash

```
var userList = {
    11234321: {
        username: 'koko',
        age: 44
    }
}
```